# getLastRow function failing when using onEdit function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a pretty simple onEdit function. When a cell within a column is changed, it should update a different sheet within the Spreadsheet (I've called this sheet the Blackbox) with the information for what was changed. I would like for the last row to in the Blackbox to be updated with any new changes. However, this only works when I specify the exact range that I want to be edited in Blackbox. If I use the getLastRow function, nothing new gets logged.

```
function onEdit(e) {

// Issuing Keys
const range = e.range;
const col = range.getColumn();
const row = range.getRow();
const lastRow = blackbox.getLastRow();

if (col === 2){
  blackbox.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(`${e.user} issued a Key`); // User
};

};
```

Comment: How is blackbox defined?

Comment: I did not include that part of the code, it is defined earlier in the sheet: const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const blackbox = ss.getSheetByName('Blackbox');

Comment: Then you did not supply a [mcve] because it's not reproducible for us.

Answer (score 2):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2) {
    const bsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Blackbox");
    bsh.getRange(bsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(`${e.user} issued a Key`); // User
  };
}
```

Comment: This works when I added "+1" to the end of getLastRow()